# Rotate an image on same page

Tags: php

I want to rotate an uploaded and retrieved image from one location. Yes i am almost done. But the problem is, due to header("content-type: image/jpeg") the page redirected to another/or image format. I want to display it in same page as original image in. Here my code..

```
     $imgnames="upload/".$_SESSION["img"];
     header("content-type: image/jpeg");
     $source=imagecreatefromjpeg($imgnames);
     $rotate=imagerotate($source,$degree,0); 
     imagejpeg($rotate);
```

i also did with css property.

```
   echo "<img src='$imgnames' style='image-orientation:".$degree."deg;' />";
```

But anyway my task is to done only with php. Please guide me, or give any reference you have

thanks advance.

Comment: You can do that e.g. with jQuery (or simple Javascript: you start with `<img id="rotImg" />` and do `document.getElementById('rotImg').src = "rotator.php?id=...";`. Your upload script will have to save the rotated image somewhere on the server, though.

Comment: yes, thanks for ur help. But my task is, it has to be done only with php. Not use css,jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    // Okay, so in your upload page 
    $imgName  = "upload/".$_SESSION["img"];
    $source=imagecreatefromjpeg($imgName);
    $rotate=imagerotate($source, $degree,0); 


    // you generate  a PHP uniqid, 
    $uniqid = uniqid();

    // and use it to store the image

    $rotImage = "upload/".$uniqid.".jpg";

    // using imagejpeg to save to a file; 

    imagejpeg($rotate, $rotImage, $quality = 75);

    // then just output a html containing ` <img src="UniqueId.000.jpg" />` 
    // and another img tag with the other file.

    print <<<IMAGES
       <img src="$imgName" />
       <img src="$rotName" />
IMAGES;

    // The browser will do the rest.
?>
```

## UPDATE

Actually, while `uniqid()` usually works, we want to use `uniqid()` *to create a file*. That's a specialized usage for which [there exists a better function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php), `tempnam()`.

Yet, `tempnam()` does not allow a custom extension to be specified, and many browsers would balk at downloading a JPEG file called "foo" instead of "foo.jpg".

To be more sure that there will not be two identical unique names we can use

```
    $uniqid = uniqid('', true);
```

adding the "true" parameter to have a longer name with more entropy.

Otherwise we need a more flexible function that will check if a unique name already exists and, if so, generate another: instead of

```
    $uniqid = uniqid();
    $rotImage = "upload/".$uniqid.".jpg";
```

we use

```
    $rotImage = uniqueFile("upload/*.jpg");
```

where `uniqueFile()` is

```
function uniqueFile($template, $more = false) {
    for ($retries = 0; $retries < 3; $retries++) {
        $testfile = preg_replace_callback(
             '#\\*#',                          // replace asterisks
             function() use($more) { 
                 return uniqid('', $more);     // with unique strings
             },
             $template                         // throughout the template
        );
        if (file_exists($testfile)) {
            continue;
        }
        // We don't want to return a filename if it has few chances of being usable
        if (!is_writeable($dir = dirname($testfile))) {
            trigger_error("Cannot create unique files in {$dir}", E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        return $testfile;
    }
    // If it doesn't work after three retries, something is seriously broken.
    trigger_error("Cannot create unique file {$template}", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: i have generated uniqid, it is 539f9c4c3ee09. But how can i store use it? please explain with example.

Comment: warning comes.. Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given in imagejpeg($rotate, $quality = 25, $rotImage);

Comment: yes, it works.. change this line imagejpeg($rotate, $quality = 25, $rotImage); to    imagejpeg($rotate, $rotImage,$quality = 25);

Comment: Sorry. I always have difficulties in remembering PHP functions' parameter order! (also, I had chosen a very poor quality setting)

Comment: @ lserni,it's ok. uniqid is the great idea. I searched lot in internet, but i cant get your idea. thanks lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the image separately - something like `<img src="path/to/image.php?id=123">`. Trying to use it as a variable like that isn't going to work.

Comment: can not understand your answer, will you please explain briefly?

Comment: @user3746107 You cannot generate an image and put out HTML in the same request like you're trying to do in your sample code. They need to be separate HTTP requests - essentially two PHP scripts, one to output the HTML, and one to output the image.

Comment: actually what happens with header(content-type)? if i remove that line machine language outpt came in browser, i am totally confused with it.

Comment: That tells the browser what content type you're giving it. Removing it means the browser doesn't know the file is a JPEG, and as a result, it tries to render it as text. You need that when you generate the image.